# Python re.split() escaping backslash

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to us python re to split strings on multiple delimiters, but it screams about my escaped backslash character.

I am not sure what to change as when I looked for escaping backslash in python, this is what I was shown is correct...

```
import re
def get_asset_str(in_str):
    split = re.split(' |/|\\' , in_str)



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AssetCheck.py", line 15, in <module>
    get_asset_str(line)
  File "AssetCheck.py", line 4, in get_asset_str
    split = re.split(' |/|\\' , in_str)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 167, in split
    return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 244, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: bogus escape (end of line)
```

Comment: That's because it's looking for the character in your regex that is being escaped.

Comment: use a raw string: `r' |/|\\'` and better instead of an alternation for single characters, use a character class: `r'[ /\\]'`

Comment: You need `' |/|\\\\'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your first backslash is escaping the second *at the level of the string literal*. But the regex engine needs *that* backslash escaped also, since it's a special character for regex too.

Use a "raw" string literal (e.g. `r' |/|\\'`) or quadruple backslash.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
import re
def get_asset_str(in_str):
    split = re.split(r' |/|\\' , in_str)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
import re

in_str = """Hello there\good/morning"""
thelist = re.split(' |/|\\\\' , in_str)
print (thelist)
```

results:

```
['Hello', 'there', 'good', 'morning']
```

Need to quad escape the backslash.  Or use raw input (I like this better but that's just me)